# Unable to install librocksdb5.8 on 19.10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I try to install `librocksdb5.8`, I get this error:

```
root@:~# sudo apt-get install -y librocksdb5.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package librocksdb5.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'librocksdb5.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'librocksdb5.8'
root@:~#
```

How do I install `librocksdb5.8` on 19.10?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the [Universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Components) to get this package. However, 19.10 uses version 5.17 instead of 5.8.

Run the following commands to enable the Universe repository and to install the package on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install librocksdb5.8
```

**Run the following commands to enable the Universe repository and to install the package on Ubuntu 19.10**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install librocksdb5.17
```

---

In the future, you can search for packages using the `apt-cache search` command like in this example:

```
apt-cache search librocksdb
```

Alternatively, you can also search for packages at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) to locate packages. This will also indicate which repository to use.

Comment: it works on ubuntu 18.04 but not on 19.10

Comment: @user3546588 Sorry, without specifying your Ubuntu version, I have to assume the latest long term support version (18.04). I have updated the answer with instructions for 19.10.